# How does React Strict Mode works?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I could find strict mode invoke certain methods twice(like constructor, render, bodies on function calls), and see they are idempotent so side effects won't be happened. And I got curious how does it works to detect unexpected side effects.

In the documents, they are talking about concurrent mode and explaining 'strict mode'. I got the concepts of it, break 'render' phase into several pieces and run it more than once(more precisely, do some works behind the scene before render).

Then how's strict mode? Do they just call certain methods twice when state get changed and create two virtual DOM and compare it?

Comment: Like Fragment, StrictMode does not render any UI, it only activates checks and adds warnings at runtime.
StrictMode checks are done in development mode only and will not affect your production build. https://medium.com/nmc-techblog/wait-youre-not-using-react-strictmode-a9713927a33b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what you can find in docs or at popular blogs, I guessing the question is about **"How is `StictMode` implemented"**.

React has a symbol to flag a usage for `StrictMode`:

> See [`Symbol.for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/for) on MDN

```
// The Symbol used to tag the ReactElement-like types
export let REACT_STRICT_MODE_TYPE = 0xeacc;
REACT_STRICT_MODE_TYPE = Symbol.for('react.strict_mode');

...
export const StrictMode = REACT_STRICT_MODE_TYPE;
```

Then when you call `React.createElement` on it, you assigning "React Strict Mode" for all nodes in the subtree.

```
typeof React.StrictMode; // symbol
<React.StrictMode />

// Transpiled to
React.createElement(React.StrictMode, ...);
```

Now, when the mode is on, React Fiber will execute extra logic for running node:

```
if (hostFiber.mode & StrictMode) {
  // ... extra logic
}
```